# Toggle state taking previous value in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to create a to-do list app. The basic functionality includes adding and deleting. So when a user selects one or multiple items, a delete button will appear and it will be deleted. My problem is I am implementing a toggle state which when a user clicks on todo item, it will be strikethrough( A strikethrough text decoration will be added via CSS).
The problem arises when I add **two items**. When I click on the first item , it gets a strike through and when I delete it, the first one goes but the **second item gets the strike through this time.**

[The running sample in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-kate-c60rn). Just try adding two items and delete the first one. The second one also gets a strike through.

I believe its because the toggle state value is being remembered.

**This is the Content.js component**

```
import "./styles/content.css";
import Individual from "./Individual";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { updateItem, markIncomplete } from "./action/action";
const Contents = (props) => {
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.todoReducer.items);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleClick = (e, isComplete, content, id) => {
    // console.log(isComplete);

    if (isComplete === false) {
      //evaluates false to true
      const newobj = {
        isComplete: true,
        content,
        id
      };

      dispatch(updateItem(newobj));

      props.deletebutton(true);
    } else {
      const falseobj = {
        isComplete: false,
        content,
        id
      };

      dispatch(markIncomplete(falseobj));
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("statechanging of contents");
  });
  return (
    <div className="content-ui">
      <div>
        {items.map((vals) => (
          <Individual
            vals={vals}
            deletebutton={props.deletebutton}
            handleClick={handleClick}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contents;
```

**This is the individual.js which deals with toggle function**

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./styles/content.css";
import { updateItem, markIncomplete } from "./action/action";
const Individual = (props) => {
  console.log("child" + props.vals.isComplete);
  const [toggle, isToggled] = useState(false);
  const handleToggle = () => {
    const mytoggle = !toggle;
    isToggled(mytoggle);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className={toggle ? "toggled" : "card-elements"}
        onMouseDown={handleToggle}
        onClick={(e) => {
          props.handleClick(
            e,
            props.vals.isComplete,
            props.vals.content,
            props.vals.id
          );
          handleToggle;
        }}
      >
        {props.vals.content}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Individual;
```

**Css of toggler**

```
.toggled {
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(94, 94, 94); */
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 3px 10px 7px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Roboto ", monospace;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.card-elements {
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(94, 94, 94); */
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 3px 10px 7px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Roboto ", monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add keys to your mapped items (there should also be a warning about this in the console).

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

As is stated from [React's documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

```js
return (
    <div className="content-ui">
      <div>
        {items.map((vals) => (
          <Individual
            key={vals.id} // <-- add unique key
            vals={vals}
            deletebutton={props.deletebutton}
            handleClick={handleClick}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```